# building html resume... should I use JSON? PHP includes? sql? xml?

Tags: html, json, xml, resume

I am building an html resume (with bootstrap tabs) but want to break the sections into separate parts for easy editing and repurposing.

For example, have the work experience data in one file, have education in another and link them to a tabbed html page, but also have the option to export to a docx or pdf. Have skills appear on the html version but not on the pdf export.

What would be the best architecture design to use? Would JSON be good or should I use PHP includes.

What about xml? or should I just maek it a mysql database and use PHP to pull that data (this seems like overkill for less than 1,000 words).

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* In addition, your question is primarily asking for opinion, which is also inappropriate for this site. This site is for **specific questions** about actual problems you're facing, not for asking for *Any ideas or suggestions* or *What platform should I use?* or *How should I design this project?*.

Comment: I knew there would be someone who would vote me down, just trying to learn. and to me, this is an actual problem I am facing. thanks for the down vote... there is always one.

Comment: No, this is not an actual **specific** problem. It's a broad, vague question asking us to recommend a framework and design your project for you. Please see [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), which specifically says broad opinion based questions are off-topic, and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically item #4 in the numbered list on that page (which I quoted above). There is nothing **specific** about *Any ideas or suggestions?*.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue any of these will be an overkill for a small project. So I'd go placing it all in one html file.

If you want to automatically generate pdf or docs it's no more a html resume. So I won't answer generating part of the question.

As for html management you can use templating language, e.g. [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) or [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

It will allow you to include html files one in another; the downside is you'll have to setup a build tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for this (which will require some basic Javascript knowledge and time).

Answer (score 1):

Something which you need to consider is the format which you would be handing into potential employers.

If you are hoping to hand in a web page, you would probably want to "render" it and not hand in a piece of functioning code. The reason for this, is if the employer/recruiter is unable to open or correctly read the file, this will decrease your chances of getting the job dramatically. Not to mention many large companies use bots which read CV's for you, [See this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/can-you-beat-bot-applicant-tracking-systems-solved-michael-peggs) which explains that matter all to you.

You would also want to consider what some companies/recruiters may think when they see `CV.html` in their email inbox. Some will think its a really smart and creative idea, others may think it is an incompatible file with their computer and may never open it. Leaving instructions on how to open the document may take time which the employer doesn't have.

I'm not saying its a ludicrous idea, I'm saying you need to properly plan it out. Personally, I would keep an *online* copy on my website, but I would also have an additional copy (Word document or PDF) which could be downloaded and accessed by those bots which I mentioned early.

In programming there are many ways to do the same thing, and it is entirely up to you and your abilities to find what is best.